# Should I2C master always send stop condition after NAK?

Tags: i2c

According to the I2C specification, there are five reasons for a NAK:

> 1. No receiver is present on the bus with the transmitted address so there is no device to respond with an acknowledgment.
> 2. The receiver is unable to receive or transmit because it is performing some real-time function and is not ready to start communication with the master.
> 3. During the transfer, the receiver gets data or commands that it does not understand.
> 4. During the transfer, the receiver cannot receive any more data bytes.
> 5. A master-receiver must signal the end of the transfer to the slave transmitter.

Should the I2C master end the communication with a stop condition in all of these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the paragraph before what you quoted from the [I2C specification](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf) (§ 3.1.6):

> When SDA remains HIGH during this ninth clock pulse, this is defined as the Not Acknowledge signal. The master can then generate either a STOP condition to abort the transfer, or a repeated START condition to start a new transfer. There are five conditions that lead to the generation of a NACK:
>
> 1. No receiver is present on the bus with the transmitted address so there is no device to respond with an acknowledge.
> 2. The receiver is unable to receive or transmit because it is performing some real-time function and is not ready to start communication with the master.
> 3. During the transfer, the receiver gets data or commands that it does not understand.
> 4. During the transfer, the receiver cannot receive any more data bytes.
> 5. A master-receiver must signal the end of the transfer to the slave transmitter

The master must not always send a stop condition, but it must send either a stop or a repeated start condition.